# why const x is ok when multi include it

Tags: c++, constants

common.h

```
int i=10

cpp one:
include "common.h"


cpp two:
include "common.h"
```

will show multiple definitions error,

but I change the code :  from int i=10 to const int i=10, it is OK.
My question is why const it is OK? what's the difference.

PS: I know the reason for why only int i=10 isn't ok, but I doesn't know why const i is ok?

Answer (score 3):

This is because `const`-qualified declarations in a namespace scope have *internal* linkage by default:

> 7.1.5.1.2. An object declared in namespace scope with a const-qualified type has internal linkage unless it is explicitly declared extern or unless it was previously declared to have external linkage.

Objects with internal linkage are not "visible" to the linker, so when you have the same declaration in several translation units, the linker would not notice. This makes sense, because all integer constants with the same value are identical to each other.

Objects without `const` qualifier, on the other hand, have external linkage. This is what causes multiple definition error during the link time.

Comment: So this is in namespace scope even with the lack of `namespace`?

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Yes, when you do not have an explicit namespace, the declaration is considered to be in the default namespace.

Answer (score 2):

a global const object doesn't need any storage.

Comment: Not true. Regardless, `extern const int i = 10;` would also define a global const object, but would not be valid in that header file because it would define a distinct object in each translation unit, just as `int i = 10;` does.

Answer (score 1):

In C language, global const variable has its address, while in c++ it is seen as a compile-time constant and put into symbol table so it is unique.

Hi, Chinese buddy :D

Comment: which country are you from? :D

Comment: qq多少，我来加下，技术无高低，都是学习中。。